# Struts2: unable to load HibernateSessionFactory.getSession() in DAO class

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, jboss

I am running an application on JBoss server which is developed using struts2 & Hibernate. But I am facing a problem in my getEmployee method of LoginDAOImpl class.The code is as below:-

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserView> getEmployee(String empId) {
    Session session = null;
    List<UserView> list = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 1 ");
        session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 2 " + session);
        String str = "from UserView  where empId='" + empId + "'";
        list = session.createQuery(str).list();
        System.out.println("LoginDAOImpl.getEmployee()::" + empId);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Config file is below:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.-->
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.90:3307/esupport
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ActionView" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.LeaveDto" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.LeaveTypeDto" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.RoleActionMap" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.RoleView" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.TimesheetTask" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.UserRoleMap" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.UserView" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeDetailsDto" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeLeave" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ItdfDetails" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.Project" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeER" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeTimesheet" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ExpenseReportDto" />
    <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.TRStatusDto" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>


On Console Iam getting "in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 1 " but i am not getting "in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 2 ".That means it is not able to find Hibernatesessionfactory class.But I have included Hibernatesessionfactory in my path. I have included jars for Hibernate :- hibernate3.jar,hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar,hibernate-annotations.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations.jar,hibernate-entitymanager.jar,hibernate-valid
```

Comment: What is the problem and the question ? Do you have an exception ? A stack trace ?

Comment: is there any problem? please show your error log hence we can help you in a better way!

Comment: Kindly add the error log if any or add clarity

Comment: guys here is the error log:-                    exception 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440) com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)

Comment: root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
 com.Allied.dao.LoginDAOImpl.getEmployee(LoginDAOImpl.java:143)
 com.Allied.service.LoginServiceImpl.getEmployee(LoginServiceImpl.java:28)
 com.Allied.action.LoginAction.loginCheck(LoginAction.java:101)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)

Answer (score 0):

Is that run in your developement environment right? Is the class complie right.I want to know that does the problem cause by environment，or the configer or the code.

Comment: Actually I am deploying the application through JBoss server in life-ray portal..i am getting exception on life-ray browser...The problem is that the compiler is not create a session..do u have any idea how to solve ??

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things that you need to check that might resolve your problem is,
1.Check the environment setup, the include path etc.
2.Check the import statements.
3.Make sure the HibernateSessionFactory belong to desired class as there may be chances that its coming from some other imported class or jar.
4.Build the project and check into its build classes directory that the .class file of same is made or not.
5.debug HibernateSessionFactory.getSession() method and find the cause of error.
Reply on the status of this problem.
Hope it solves your issue.